# Problem with Lightbox when included in production site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set up the Lightbox as it is explained in the official tutorial and it works perfect on my local server.Then a guy decided to include it to his production site like this:

```
http://mysqite.bg/index.php?showoffer=yes&id=11&testinclude.=test/jsgallery/jsgallery.php
```

And that led to the fact that when you click on a picture it's opened in a new window without any overlay.

I tried this : http://mysite.bg/index.php?testinclude.=test/jsgallery/jsgallery.php

And it works almost fine with the exception that the Close button at the bottom of the picture is not displayed.

```
    showoffer=yes&id=11
```

Is used to call some kind of flash/javascript advertisement, but I can't figure out what the problem is, mostly because I don't have access to the `index.php` file.Do I really need to overwrite something in the `index.php` to get lightbox working, or I can do it from the index file in the lightbox directory, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://promo.aqualand.bg/test/jsgallery/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://promo.aqualand.bg/test/jsgallery/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://promo.aqualand.bg/test/jsgallery/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://promo.aqualand.bg/test/jsgallery/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <title></title>
<script>
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


     $j(document).ready(function(){
       $j("div").hide();
     });


     $('someid').hide();
   </script>



</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:450px;">
<?php
  $db_connect = mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '*****');
        if(!$db_connect)
                {
                         die('Не може да се осъществи връзка с базата данни' . mysql_error());
                }
  mysql_select_db("Beta_tester", $db_connect);
  $rs = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE oferta_id=2');


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
        echo '<a href="'.$row['location'].'" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="'.$row['location'].'" width="110" height="90" margin-left="10" alt="image" /></a>';

  }

?>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Along with an eventual solution I really would like to know do you think this could be solved without changing the main index file?

Thanks

Leron

P.S I changed the lighbox index file leavng only `<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>` and now the gallery don't even show up...

Answer (score 0):

isn't it simply a missing image file for your close button? he included your script but not the images, right?

Comment: No, the main problem is that I dont get the Lighbox overlay effect at all, but instead when i click on a picture the large picture is shown on a new page, without any styling, effects or whatever...see above if you want I've insert P.S

Comment: well, that just means the whole plugin doesn't work, mate. you can't just include your script file and expect it to work. Plugin normally comes with a bunch of javascript, css and image files. They all required for LightBox to work properly.